# Service crash issue in Ubuntu 18

Tags: linux, crash, gdb, static-libraries, ubuntu-18.04

I have one static library, when I'm trying to create object of class from the static library in servicemain I'm getting crash on service startup.
When I disable the call static library classes, Service works fine.

I'm  using Poco library for Service Handler, in crash dump we get callstack of Poco library only and not a single trace of our static library so not able to find out the root cause.  Code is working fine on Ubuntu 16 and 14.

Below is the stack trace.

```
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007f799927f801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007f799e7cc755 in Poco::SignalHandler::handleSignal(int) ()
   from /lib/libPocoFoundation.so.60
#3  <signal handler called>
#4  0x00007f799bb09b40 in std::string::clear() () from /lib/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x0000563554610794 in Poco::Path::clear (this=0x7fffabfdd3e0) at src/Path.cpp:597
#6  0x00007f799e7bc5e1 in Poco::Path::parseUnix(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /lib/libPocoFoundation.so.60
#7  0x00007f799e7bc889 in Poco::Path::assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /lib/libPocoFoundation.so.60
#8  0x00007f799e7bc916 in Poco::Path::Path(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /lib/libPocoFoundation.so.60
#9  0x00007f799e483e56 in Poco::Util::Application::getApplicationPath(Poco::Path&) const ()
   from /lib/libPocoUtil.so.60
#10 0x00007f799e48565c in Poco::Util::Application::init() () from /lib/libPocoUtil.so.60
#11 0x00007f799e49708c in Poco::Util::ServerApplication::run(int, char**) ()
   from /lib/libPocoUtil.so.60
#12 0x0000563554107544 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffabfdd958) at ../../../src/servicemain/main.cpp:22
(gdb)
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

> not a single trace of our static library

Your stack trace is suspicious: why does (almost) *every* frame *except* frame #5 come from `/lib/libPocoUtil.so.60`, while frame #5 comes from `src/Path.cpp:597` compiled into the main executable?

I suspect that your static library for some reason provides a *definition* of `Poco::Path::clear()`, and that definition:

1. Is incompatible with `libPocoUtil.so.60` and
2. Wins over the definition provided in `libPocoUtil.so.60`.

You'll need to figure out how `src/Path.cpp` ended up in your binary, and removing that will fix your crash.

**Update:**

> There are references of Path.hpp of boost in my static library. Could that be reason ?

There could be any number of reasons. You need to investigate why `src/Path.cpp` is linked into the main executable (is it your code, or is it part of `Poco`?), and why it *defines* the `Poco::Path::clear()` method.

For a start, edit your question and show code around line 597 in `src/Path.cpp`.

Comment: There are references of Path.hpp of boost in my static library. Could that be reason ?

Comment: @nandkumar I've updated the answer -- you need to supply a _lot_ more details if you need help understanding this.